# Reset input box fields on each time using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Each time I submit the input text values, I'm getting the total result value in a string: for `20` + `20` I will get `'2020'`, but for a single hit I'm getting the proper – numerical – answer; how can I avoid this and retrieve the correct answer?

Below is image the image showing the current result:

[image]

```js
function sendInveMess() {}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#result_display").click(function() {

    var result = $('#paper1_internals').val();
    var result2 = $('#paper1_externals').val();
    var res = parseInt(result) + parseInt(result2);
    var result_add = $("#paper1_total").append(res);

    var result3 = $('#paper2_internals').val();
    var result4 = $('#paper2_externals').val();
    var res2 = parseInt(result3) + parseInt(result4);
    var result_add2 = $("#paper2_total").append(res2);

    var result5 = $('#paper3_internals').val();
    var result6 = $('#paper3_externals').val();
    var res3 = parseInt(result5) + parseInt(result6);
    var result_add3 = $("#paper3_total").append(res3);

    var result7 = $('#paper4_internals').val();
    var result8 = $('#paper4_externals').val();
    var res4 = parseInt(result7) + parseInt(result8);
    var result_add4 = $("#paper4_total").append(res4);

    var grand_total_cal = parseInt(res) + parseInt(res2) + parseInt(res3) + parseInt(res4);
    var grand_value = $("#grand_tot").append(grand_total_cal);

    var perc_cal = (((parseFloat(res) + parseFloat(res2) + parseFloat(res3) + parseFloat(res4)) / 600) * 100).toFixed(2);
    $("#marks_percentile").append(perc_cal).append("%");
    if (perc_cal <= 50) {
      $("#class_rate").append("fail");
    } else if (perc_cal >= 60) {
      $("#class_rate").append("first classs");
    } else if (perc_cal >= 70) {
      $("#class_rate").append("first classs with distiction");
    }

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Internals</th>
    <th>Externals</th>
    <th class="total">Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Paper 1</th>
    <td><input id="paper1_internals" type="text" name="paper1_internals"></td>
    <td><input id="paper1_externals" type="text" name="paper1_externals"></td>
    <td id="paper1_total" class="result"><span></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="width_large" colspan="2">
      <div id="grand_tot">Grand Total = </div>
    </td>
    <td class="width_large" colspan="2">
      <div id="marks_percentile">Total Percentile = <span></span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="border_less">
    <td class="width_full">
      <div id="class_rate" class="width_large grade"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="result_display" onclick="return sendInveMess();" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to add 20+20 and want to get 40, but it comes out as '2020' ?

Comment: Please include all relevant code

Comment: @ProEvilz , yes

Comment: @delip, clearly, there is a lot of parseInt use already.

Comment: I think the problem is your use of append, but without know what `$("#paper3_total")` is, then it should either be `.val()` or `.text()`

Comment: @ashishvc And it is var `grand_total_cal` that comes out in string format? or is it when you add to the DOM? Please `console.log(grand_total_cal);` to see if your value is really calculated correctly otherwise it could be a HTML issue because you use `append()` and not `val()`

Comment: @carsten lovbo andersen , $("#paper3_total") is this  <td id="paper3_total" class="result"></td>

Comment: Without your HTML we can *guess* at the reasons (as [Carsten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909236/how-to-reset-input-box-fields-on-each-time-using-jquery#comment80765178_46909236) and [renatokr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46909297/82548) already have). If you can show your HTML, though, we can offer specific answers and - coincidentally - probably also show you how to shorten the code you've used (which while mostly functional does trigger my DRY itch (unfortunate phrasing aside)). Please, read the "*[mcve]*" guidelines to understand what we expect from question code.

Comment: @david Thomos i have updated with html content as a img format , because i din able to post full html content

Comment: I appreciate the thought; but we can't debug an image. Copy and paste the HTML into the question in the same way as the CSS, that way we can reproduce your problem in order to more easily solve it.

Comment: By the way, you'll never reach the `else if (perc_cal >= 70)` statement.

Comment: @david Thomas i have updated the html code

Comment: You can read a solution in my working example. You can try it by clicking the "Run code snippet" button. I had a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example:

```js
  
$(document).ready(function(){  
        $("#result_display").click(function(){
        
          let tableRes        = {}
            , grand_total_cal = 0
            , perc_cal        = 0.0
            , i               = 1
            , rows_count      = 2 ;
        
          for( ; i <= rows_count ; ++i )
          {
            tableRes[i] = {
                prefix: "#paper"+i
              , int: null
              , ext: null
              , res: null
              , add: null // ???
            }
        
            // For convenience
            tres = tableRes[i] ;
        
            // Get values
            for(from of ['int', 'ext']) {
              tres[from] = $(tres.prefix + '_' + from + 'ernals').val();
            }
          
            // Calc res
            tres.res = parseInt(tres.int) + parseInt(tres.ext);
        
            // Add res (???)
            tres.add = $(tres.prefix + '_total').text(tres.res);
  
            // Increment total and percents
            grand_total_cal += tres.res ;
            perc_cal        += parseFloat(tres.res) ;
          }
  

          
          // Calc final percent
          perc_cal = ( ( perc_cal/600 ) * 100 ).toFixed(2) ;
        
          // Display the results
          var grand_value = $("#grand_tot").text(grand_total_cal) ; 
          $( "#marks_percentile" ).text(perc_cal).append("%"); 
        
         $("#class_rate").text(function(perc){
           if      (perc > 69){ return "first classs with distiction";}
           else if (perc > 59){ return "first classs";} 
           else               { return "fail"; }
           }(perc_cal))
       })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Internals</th>
            <th>Externals</th>
            <th class="total">Total</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Paper 1</th>
            <td><input id="paper1_internals" type="text" name="paper1_internals"></td>
            <td><input  id="paper1_externals" type="text" name="paper1_externals"></td>
            <td id="paper1_total" class="result"><span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Paper 2</th>
            <td><input id="paper2_internals" type="text" name="paper2_internals"></td>
            <td><input  id="paper2_externals" type="text" name="paper2_externals"></td>
            <td id="paper2_total" class="result"><span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="width_large">
        <div id="grand_tot">Grand Total = </div>
                </td>
            <td class="width_large">
        <div id="marks_percentile">Total Percentile = <span></span></div>
                </td>
        </tr>
          <tr class="border_less">
              <td class="width_full">
                <div id="class_rate" class="width_large grade"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="result_display" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: if you submit more then twice it is resulting twice , i mean for one time submit it will result like this 12 + 12 = 24, after hitting second time it will result 2424

Comment: Fixed ;-). Try it again. You shouldn't use 'append' (means 'add').

Answer (score 1):

you are using append, you need to clear before inserting the text

change innerHtml instead if it's a span

Comment: Not 'innerHtml' (not a function), but 'text' (jQuery solution)

Comment: innerHTML is not a function, so this solution is obviously not working. So it's not an answer. Moreover, 'innerHTML' works not only on a span element. So this answer is false twice. Plus: he don't need to 'clear before'. He just have to 'replace'. So this answer is false third times. ;-) Sorry dude.

Comment: pff, please read https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Comment: @renatokr, it seems you don't know what is a property and what is a function, and you don't know what is a span… Please read deeper w3schools page(s). `innerHTML` is a `property` (you set/get it with `=`). jQuery's `text' is a function (you set the value as an argument). Plus, innerHTML works with merely all tags, DIV, SPAN, A, SECTION and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Append will add the text to existing value. you should use `.val(res)` to set result value.
Try this out. It will update the value everytime you submit

```
var result = $('#paper1_internals').val();
var result2 = $('#paper1_externals').val();                
var res = parseInt(result) + parseInt(result2);            
$("#paper1_total").val(res);
var result_add = $("#paper1_total").val();
```

Similarly do for rest of the textbox combinations.

Comment: i din get the value of total when i did like this

Comment: i used .text and it worked fine for me , anyway your answer also correct